# Alter table to enable RLS does not work in a transaction when executing a script

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have this script saved as `db.sql`:

```
begin;

    create schema api;

    create table api.users(
        id serial primary key,
        name text
    );

    insert into api.users(id, name) values
    (1, 'alex'),
    (2, 'john');

    grant usage on schema api to public;

    grant all on api.users to public;

    alter table api.users force row level security;

commit;
```

Which I execute with `psql -h localhost -U postgres -f db.sql -w app`, but when I run `SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relrowsecurity = 'true';` no result is given.
After running `alter table api.users force row level security;` again the previous query does return the users table.

It seems that altering the table in a transaction does not work.

Comment: table api.users in psql should be the same as select * from api.users as far as I know

Comment: are you sure that `client()` is filled when called? maybe it's empty ...

Comment: It returns 'a' as it should, and if it would have been empty no row should have been returned, no?

Comment: related to other servers perhaps you've to deny access for all and only grant if `client()` is found. Sorry never working with pgsql, so I don't know the details and can only answer general.

Comment: The point is you make a check based on `client()` but no restriction if I see it right.